# Designing eye-glasses with a small magnification and fixed focal distance?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Is it possible to design eye glasses that sit 2 cm from the eye such that an object of height $h_o$ and distance 20 m is magnified to a height $h_i = 1.2 \cdot h_o$? How complex would such a system be?

Take the below imaging system:
[image]

The equations governing the behaviour of this system are:

$m=\frac{h_i}{h_o} = \frac{f_i}{f_o}$

Hence,

$f_i = m\cdot f_o$

In my example, the focal distance $f_o$ and $f_i$ are most important, therefore a magnification of 1000 would be required to satisfy the equations. Obviously, that's unrealistic. I understand that the distance between the objective and imaging lenses can effectively be anything, since the ray is collimated at this point.

How would I go about designing the optics to satisfy the requirements I've stated?